# How to override inherited dimensions?

Tags: css

How to prevent elements from inheriting dimensions of parent elements?
Example HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Problem</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .main li a {
                height: 80px;
                width: 150px;
                background: #ff00ff;
                margin-bottom: 1px;
                display: block;
            }
            .sub li a {
                display: block;
                background: #00ff00;
            }           
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <ul class="main">
                <li>
                    <a>Item 1</a>
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a>Subitem 1 - this should not inherit height of 80px</a></li>
                        <li><a>Subitem 2 - this should not inherit height of 80px</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Item 2</a></li>              
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The .sub li a is inheriting the width and height of .main li a and I don't know why. I have to set the width and height for the outer li but the inner li should have width and height as needed. I can unset inherited float for example by using float:none but I don't know how to reset the specified dimensions so that they do not apply to the sub elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your `li`s are `display: block` elements? In that case, they don't really *inherit* the parent item's width, but they are `width: 100%` by default.

I don't think you'll get around setting an explicit width for the inner `li` in that case.

Comment: I've made a little example so you can see what's the problem. I've defined the height for .main li a but I don't see why .sub li a is inheriting any of it!

Comment: @A-OK ah, that is different. Well, it's not really *inheriting* the height, but the CSS rule applies to the element directly. Try `height: auto` in the sub li or `.main > li > a` in the first rule, but that will break in IE6

Comment: But why should the CSS rule apply? It's for .main li a and the sub element is .main li .sub li a

Comment: @A-OK because `.sub` is a child of `.main`, and in your rule, what you are saying is "any `a` inside a `li` inside `.main`. That's how CSS works. The child selector `>` limits rules to immediate children

Comment: By the way, height: auto; works in all browsers except in IE6 where it's a bit different but I'll fix it somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's not inheritance. The selector `.main li a` applies equally to *all* `a` tags within the `li` within the element with the `main` class. What you're asking is for this rule to not apply. Three suggestions.

Option 1: Change the first CSS selector to:

```
.main li > a
```

This means "only a tags which are the immediate children of the `li`". However, support for this syntax on older browsers is not great.

Option 2: Add "height: auto;" to the `.sub` CSS rule. Again, this will work on newer browsers, but older browsers don't necessarily implement it properly.

Option 3: Add a class to the first `a` tag, and change the first CSS selector to

`.main li a.yourClass`

This prevents the height and the other rules applying to any `a` tags that don't have the class. This will work well across all browsers, even terrible old ones.